# How to render a questionnaire component in React/Redux only one time, the first time user logs into my webapp(MERN)?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I am building an app where after login, the user has access to a dashboard which contains links for different components. I want to render a questionnaire only the first time ever the user logs in to my webapp. Would I necessarily need to store an attribute of the kind FirstLogin in my database and set it on and off according to the render information of each component? I am wondering if I can somehow use the Redux store to save the FirstLogin information or deal in local component storage by passing props to my questionnaire component that belong to the parent(dashboard) component, to which the user is redirected after filling the questionnaire?

Answer (score 0):

The user may not login to you app after signing up. He may clear the cache.

So its better to add a flag column in your database. It may also help you in the future

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365471/how-to-fetch-data-in-react-redux-from-mongoose-mongodb-using-router-to-reflect-c

Comment: Could you kindly see my code and guide me to how I can make it work?